# Получить размер файла

Tags: файлы, visual-c++

Нужно получить размер файла по его абсолютному пути в виде `String ^`. Как это сделать?

Comment: так понимаю  на Windows?

Comment: @Komdosh  да. Основная проблема заключается в том, что надо вызвать функцию именно по пути в виде `String ^`.

Comment: @Komdosh ну как? Я так и не отрыл.

Comment: а от неё можно взять c_str()?

Comment: @Komdosh да, можно.

Comment: Вроде нашёл решение, долго вспоминал, где видел `^`, это же `.net`?

Comment: на крайний случай можно взять `c_str()` и пойти `С` способом с открытием файла и чтением байт.

Comment: @Komdosh да, я пишу всякую бурду на WinForms =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так вроде должно сработать

```
String^ path = "file.txt";
FileInfo^ fi = gcnew FileInfo( path );  

Console::WriteLine("file size: {0}", fi->Length );
```